# ng serve para de carregar quando chega em 70% no Ubuntu

Tags: angular, ubuntu

Estou tentando rodar minha aplicação angular 2, mas ao executar o comando **ng serve** ele carrega só até 70%.

Fica com essa mensagem:

> "70% building modules 748/748 modules 0 active"

Já fiz o `npm uninstall` do angular/cli, instalei de novo e continua com o mesmo problema.

Comment: Qual a sua versão do Angular e co CLI ?

Comment: Angular: 4.0.0
Angular CLI: 1.6.5
Node: 8.9.4
OS: linux x64